# How can i sort the directory content by owner and group rights in terminal?

Tags: linux, sorting, terminal

Owner rights have a priority over group rights during sorting.

i thought something like ls -la | sort -n

The first letter though,that shows the type of the file gets in the way and gets counted as well.
How can i start sorting based on the 2nd column where owner rights start?(not 2nd field,terminal column)
If this is not possible,if there s any other solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk (works only in gawk) program to do it:

```
NR==2,true {
    arr[substr($0, 2)] = $0
}
END {
    asorti(arr, sorted)
    for (i in sorted)
        print arr[sorted[i]]
}
```

here is how to run it: `ls -l | awk -f prog.awk`

What it does:

```
NR==2,true {
```

takes every line between the second one and the last one (to omit column header)

```
arr[substr($0, 2)] = $0
```

take the whole line and save it in associative array called `arr` under index that is the same as the whole line except it does not have the first letter

```
END {
```

after reading all lines

```
asorti(arr, sorted)
```

sort the array by the indices (gnu extension) and store the sorted array in `sorted`. The sorted array is indited by the element's position and the values are the original indices ( the lines without first letter)

```
for (i in sorted)
    print arr[sorted[i]]
```

iterate the sorted indices and retrieve the original lines from the initial array `arr`.

The advantage of this method is that it saves all the information about the entries (including whether it's a link or directory or something else).

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of ls through cut?

```
ls -lA| cut -d ' ' -f2- | sort -n
```

`cut` will keep all columns starting with column2 and the output is then piped to sort.